# How to get array from php xpath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a `var_dump($v)` like this:

```
 object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(6) "ff_row"
    }
    ["span"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "aaa"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "bbb"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "ccc"
    }
    }
  }
```

How can I create the array of：

```
array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(6) "aaa"
          [1]=>
          string(9) "bbb"
          [2]=>
          string(6) "ccc"
        }
```

I tried `$r = $v['span']` to create the array, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try...

```
$v = (array) $v;
$r = $v['span'];
```